# Bootstrap 3.3.2 and JQueryUI : obtaining an autocompleting input in a popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, popover

I tried to activate a list of items using the JQueryUI autocomplete function in an input field contained into a form, itself contained into a bootstrap popover, but I failed.

I had the same trouble while doing the same with a Bootstrap modal, but i solved the issue by defining the following CSS property :

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to be sufficient to solve the issus when a popover is concerned.

Any idea to solve the trouble ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "input field contained into a form holder by a bootstrap popover"

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake in the formulation. I just edited my post to be more understandable.